# Symfony - How to access values from [EntityName].orm.yml inside [EntityName]Type.php?

Tags: php, validation, yaml, symfony

Assume I have a Entity `Car`:

```
Class Car {

    $private name;
    //...
}
```

And an appropriate `Car.orm.yml` file for doctrine:

```
...\Bundle\CarBundle\Entity\Car: 
...
fields:
  name:
    type: string
    length: 100
    ...
```

Inside the appropriate `CarType` class I want to access the `length` value of the `Car.orm.yml` file:

```
 class CarType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder 
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('maxlength' => 100),// Access length here!
            ))
            //...
    }
}
```

How can I access the `length` value of the `Car.orm.yml` inside `CarType` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all accessible through entity metadata.

1. http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html#define-your-form-as-a-service
2. Add entity manager as a dependency.
3. Get class metadata via full class name:

   ```
   $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata('Bundle\CarBundle\Entity\Car')
   ```
4. Get field definition:

   ```
   $classMetadata->getFieldMapping('name')['length']
   ```